# Probability Problem.. Help

Tags: probability, probability-theory

*We have a series of independent throws of a regular die. Let $X$ be the number of throws until the die shows the number $3$ for the second time. Next, from a box containing 7 red and 3 green balls we randomly select $X$ balls (we put the ball back again before taking the next one) and let $Y$ be the number of red balls we chose. Calculate the probability $P(Y=1)$*

Here's what I've done so far:

$P(X=x)=\binom{x}{1}\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right )^{2}(\frac{5}{6})^{x-2}$

$P(Y=1|X=x)=\binom{x}{1}\left ( \frac{7}{10} \right )(\frac{3}{10})^{x-1}$

$P(X=x|Y=1)=\frac{P(X=x)P(Y=1|X=x)}{P(Y=1)}\Leftrightarrow P(Y=1)=\frac{P(X=x)P(Y=1|X=x)}{P(X=x|Y=1)}$

But I dont' know how to proceed since I don't know how to find $P(X=x|Y=1)$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Leave out the third line and proceed with: $$P(Y=1)=\sum_xP(Y=1\mid X=x)P(X=x)$$

Comment: Nice! You think the other two statements about P(X=x) and P(Y=1|X=x) are correct?

Comment: I think that the binomial in the expression of $P(X=x)$ must be $\binom{x-1}1=x-1$. The statements about $P(Y=1∣X=x)$ are correct. But they are not quite useful here. These are only expressions concerning the relation between probabilities $P(A∣B),P(A),P(B),P(B∣A)$.